# React hook dependency when listening to incoming url

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a function that listens to incoming deeplink urls:

```
useEffect(() => {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl);
  return () => {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrl);
  };
}, [handleUrl]);
```

I have a function to handle the incoming url:

```
  const handleUrl = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const { url }: { url: string } = event;
      if (user) {
        alert("Hello user!")
        ...
      }
    },
    [user]
  );
```

Say I authenticate the user by opening the URL `exp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/auth?key=zxcvbn`
`handleUrl` runs, authenticates the user and shows a pop up saying "Hello user".
Then the user updates their profile. The user is updated and `handleUrl` will re-run because there is a change to `user` which is a dependency. The user gets another pop up that says "Hello user".
I obviously don't want that.

I was thinking to perhaps change the URL with Linking, but that is messy, and also feels like a workaround.

Should I remove the `user` dependency from the array? But then I get the eslint error. Should I ignore it? Is it right to ignore?

What the best approach to handling this?

Comment: I would not change the user in the `handleUrl` and depend on it at the same time. If you are setting it in that function, you already have the `user` data available in that context.

Comment: @Christiaanthe user is a stateful object. I use a State store to handle updating the user. It's not created inside handleUrl and it is not updated in there either. However, in the function I do check the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution - ignore the eslint error. It's best practice to be careful of what variables you have in your effects - thus eslint expects you to have "user" in there but its not always detrimental to your code.

If you would like to keep it in the dependencies still you could make use of a usePrevious hook where you could compare and if the user object is different then don't show the popup.

usePrevious Hook:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable 
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes


  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

then in you could do something like:

```
const prevUser = usePrevious(user);
const handleUrl = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const { url }: { url: string } = event;
      if (user.whatever == prevUser.whatever) {
        alert("Hello user!")
        ...
      }
    },
    [user, prevUser]
  );
```

Comment: OK, so this confirms my initial intuition that adding user as a dependency here has a negative effect. Thanks for sharing your possible solution, which I will avoid because it's really not necessary in this case, but it was good to mention.